# Максимальное значение в массиве си

Tags: c, массивы

В общем, задача очень была очень простой. Нужно было просто найти минимальный элемент массива, но сделать это через доп.функцию с её последующим вызовом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_number(int arr[])
{
    int max;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    if (arr[i]>arr[0])
    max=arr[i];
    }
return max;
}


int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    int max;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    if (arr[i]<0)
    arr[i]*=-1;
    }
    
    max_number(arr);
    printf ("%d", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Как я понял, вызов функции он вообще не видит и выводит в консоль 21845. В этом всём сильно путаюсь, буду благодарен ответам.

Comment: *максимальный..

Comment: Очередной любитель отключать предупреждения о неинициализированных переменных... Чему у вас равно `max` в ` max_number` при входе в цикл? И, кстати о цикле - а если задание изменится, и массив будет из 6 элементов, что вы будете делать? Но и это не все - если вы результат вычисления функции просто выбрасываете, то с чего вы решили, что он будет выведен на экран? У вас примерно получается - иду на рыбалку с ведром. Наловил рыбу, выбросил ведро с рыбой в речку, иду домой. Прихожу, беру **другое** ведро и удивляюсь - где же рыба? Ведро ведь точно такое же, а рыбы нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, в условии вы ясно написали:

> Нужно было просто найти **минимальный** элемент массива, но сделать это через доп.функцию с её последующим вызовом.

Вы же ищете максимальный. Далее, вы не передаете размер массива в функцию, не инициализируете переменные.

Вот правильное решение:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min_number(int* arr, unsigned int size) {
    int min = arr[0];

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];

    return min;
    }


int main() {
    int arr[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

        if (arr[i] < 0)
            arr[i] *= -1;
        }

    printf("%d", min_number(arr, 5));
    }
```

Ваше изменение знака

```
if (arr[i] < 0) arr[i] *= -1;
```

оставляю на вашей совести - об этом в условии ничего не говорится.

Answer (score 2):

место:

```
if (arr[i]>arr[0])
    max=arr[i];
```

надо:

```
if (arr[i] > max)
    max = arr[i];
```

---

место:

```
max_number(arr);
```

надо:

```
max = max_numder(arr);
```

Comment: Переменная `max` в функции `max_number` не инициализирована.